# How to fix AS3 XML node selection by attribute value not working?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

Before start, I've already searched SO for this issue and also googled and found nothing. I know how to selec a node by its attribute value and already used the same syntax in other projects I've done before.

**The problem:**

When I trace `describeType(objectClass).factory.implementsInterface` i get:

```
<implementsInterface type="flash.events::IEventDispatcher" />
<implementsInterface type="flash.display::IBitmapDrawable" />
<implementsInterface type="com.rcdmk.objectPooling::IPoolable" />
```

But when I trace `describeType(objectClass).factory.implementsInterface.(@type == "com.rcdmk.objectPooling::IPoolable")` i get nothing.

I whant to select the node with the attribute `type` equals `com.rcdmk.objectPooling::IPoolable`.

What I'm missing here and how can I check if this `objectClass` implements the `IPoolable` interface in case its a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this before as well. If the node contains nothing, when you trace it, it *is* nothing.  But this should give you an XMLList, which should have a length().

Comment: Oh, thanks. I was boiled with some other problems that I couldn't remember of that. Also, my problem was a check involving this and an inverse condition.